# Double integration question with exponential

Tags: calculus, integration

$$I=\int_{0}^1 \int_{\sqrt{x}}^1  \mathrm e^{y^3}dydx$$

I have attached my solution [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOZWa.png)

Is this correct?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is correct; the exchange of the integration order uses [Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem). See also [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) guide on MathJax, as we prefer it to uploading an image.